# Python close a while

Tags: python

Hello i have made this simple program but i have a problem. All the program works good but at the end after i answer the final question "Do you want to make another operation? yes or no" and i choose no, the window of the input don't close. (this probably mean that i don't have closed properly the while loop). How i can close the while correctly ?

CODE :

```
def multiplication(b, c):

   a=b*c

   return a

def division(b, c):

   a=b/c

   return a

def main():

    Menu = input("""Choose one operation :

    1.Multiplication
    2.Division

    -------------------->""")

   if Menu=="1":

       b=float(input("Insert a number"))
       c=float(input("Insert a number"))

       print("Result :",multiplication(b, c))

   elif Menu=="2":

       b=float(input("Insert a number"))
       c=float(input("Insert a number"))

       print("Result :",division(b, c))

 main()


 while True:

    while True:

        cont=input("Do you want to make another operation? yes or no")

        if cont=="yes":

            main()

        else:

            print ("Close")
            break
```

Comment: Why do you have *two* `while` loops inside of each other?

Comment: You have **two** `while` loops. Remove the outer one, un-indent the body.

Comment: ok now works, thank you ....

Answer (score 0):

You have to `while` Loop. Remove the outer one and it'll work.
Also unhindent the inner `while` loop